# Rank with a tie breaker in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have a query where after merging a few tables together, I'm trying to rank data based on three calculated metrics that are individually ranked.  Those metrics are:

- IP_PER_DAY
- CR (Close Rate)
- AVERAGE TICKET

What I'm doing is adding up the ranked values and then ranking that number but if there is a tie between the summed ranked values, PQ just assigns the same ranking (RankKind=Competition).  What I'm wanting to do is sum up the rankings for the three metrics above and IF there is a tie between the three summed rankings, I'd like to use the highest SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN as the tiebreaker.

Wisdom is greatly appreciated.

```
let
Source = #"365",
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"REGION"}, {{"I_SALES", each List.Sum([I_SALES]), type nullable number}, {"NO_OF_I", each List.Sum([NO_OF_I]), type number}, {"I_PLAN", each List.Sum([I_PLAN]), type nullable number}, {"IP_ISSUED", each List.Sum([IP_ISSUED]), type nullable number}, {"IP_REJECTED", each List.Sum([IP_REJECTED]), type nullable number}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "TIMEFRAME", each 365),
SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN", each [I_SALES]/[I_PLAN]),
IP_PER_DAY = Table.AddColumn(SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN, "IP / Day", each ([IP_ISSUED]-[IP_REJECTED])/[TIMEFRAME]),
IP_DAY_RANK = Table.AddRankColumn(IP_PER_DAY,"IP / Day Rank",{"IPASS / Day",Order.Descending}),
CR = Table.AddColumn(IP_DAY_RANK, "CR", each [NO_OF_I]/([IP_ISSUED]-[IP_REJECTED])),
CR_RANK = Table.AddRankColumn(CR,"Close Rate Rank",{"CR",Order.Descending}),
AVERAGE_TICKET = Table.AddColumn(CR_RANK, "AVERAGE_TICKET", each [I_SALES]/[NO_OF_I]),
AVERAGE_TICKET_RANK = Table.AddRankColumn(AVERAGE_TICKET,"Average Ticket Rank",{"AVERAGE_TICKET",Order.Descending}),
TOTAL_POINTS = Table.AddColumn(AVERAGE_TICKET_RANK, "TOTAL_POINTS", each [#"IPASS / Day Rank"]+[Close Rate Rank]+[Average Ticket Rank]),
SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN_RANK = Table.AddRankColumn(TOTAL_POINTS,"Sales % to Plan Rank",{"SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN",Order.Descending}),
POWER_RANK = Table.AddRankColumn(SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN_RANK,"ACT Power Rank",{"TOTAL_POINTS",Order.Ascending},[RankKind=RankKind.Competition])
```

in
POWER_RANK

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the column to your list of columns in the order you wish it considered.

```
POWER_RANK = Table.AddRankColumn(SALES_PCT_TO_PLAN_RANK,"ACT Power Rank",{"TOTAL_POINTS","Sales % to Plan Rank"},[RankKind=RankKind.Competition])
```

[image]

*Note that the above relies on the default **Order.Ascending** sort order. You can expand the argument to include the desired sort order for each column with the same syntax used in `Table.Sort`*

```
    #"Add Rank Column" = Table.AddRankColumn(#"Previous Step","Rank", 
        {
            {"Column1",Order.Ascending},
            {"Column2",Order.Ascending}
        },
            [RankKind=RankKind.Competition])
```